X509Store can't find a certificate by subject name
Suddenly (customer reported a service failing for 'some time'), I'm not able to find a certificate anymore.
The certificate is in the list of all certificates in the given store but can't be found with (part of) its subject name (example, the app uses a configurable subject name):
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

// it's in the list...
var subject = store.Certificates[0].Subject;
Console.WriteLine(subject); // CN=CertName, OU=...
var subName = subject.Substring(3, 6);
Console.WriteLine(subName); // CertNa

// ...but can't be found
var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, subName, false);
Console.WriteLine(certs.Count); // 0

The (valid) certificate is the only one in that store. Also, checking private key ACL etc. showed no suspect values. And as I can list the certificate, I should be able to find it too. No? Why not?

This is more "psychic debugging" than answering the question, but I'll guess that the match string is crossing attributes.
// it's in the list...
var subject = store.Certificates[0].Subject;
Console.WriteLine(subject); // CN=CertName, OU=...
var subName = subject.Substring(3, 6);
Console.WriteLine(subName); // CertNa

My guess is that you've never seen that fail.  But they possibly searched for CN=CertNa.  That will (basically) never match on FindBySubjectName, because it doesn't use the same string representation as cert.Subject.
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/40bc2d88b6606324f5774cc972d480a1d26084f8/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography/tests/X509Certificates/FindTests.cs#L327-L370 show what does/doesn't get matched in practice, but basically if you think of a subject as being CN=Common Name, OU=Organizational Unit, O=Organization, L=Locality, S=State, C=Country, then FindBySubjectName does "Country, State, Locality, Organization, Organizational Unit, Common Name".ContainsIgnoreCase(input).  That is it's reversed from the order you expect (which is, amusingly, itself called "Reversed"), and it doesn't contain the attribute labels and equals signs.
Since the .NET tests for this haven't changed here over the history of .NET Core/.NET 5+, neither .NET nor Windows have changed the match logic.  So if it was working, then stopped, then perhaps the actual problem is that the certificate got renewed and no longer matches under the (non-obvious) string that gets tested.
(Changing to the blame view says that those tests haven't changed since Oct 5, 2015, when FindBySubject support was added on non-Windows systems)

Thanks for that elaborate response. Unfortunately, I double-checked that the string we search for is a strict substring of the Common Name itself. The application itself (.NET 4.5) is not under active development anymore and does not use above code but attempts to load the cert by subject name from a config file. I checked by reproducing in PowerShell on the application server  The certificate is valid until next year and has not been renewed recently (it's a lengthy manual process to get a new one from the issuer).
